# C# solution and source file corrupted due to windows system crash

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, crash

I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010.

My system crashed. Now, I am not able to open my C# project solution file.

The source file also corrupted. In Notepad++, its showing NULL characters. However, size of the file is correct.

How can I solve this problem? I really need the project, as it is very important to me.

**EDIT:
I find the solution. I used this program (http://ilspy.net/) and able to find the source code from its binary file. Thanks to everyone.**

Comment: Well, just restore your project from backup. You're doing backups of important projects, don't you?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, my backups are quite old. I need current one. I have added many lines to it and don't want to start from beginning.

Comment: Well, you can run some filesystem checker (either built-in or some third-party), and probably it can restore *some* information from your files. But I would not rely on it.

Comment: If the file is corrupt, and you don't have a current backup, you are forked.

This is why people use source control.  Source Control in Visual Studio is free with Visual Studio Online for up to 5 users.  If you had your project in source control this wouldn't have happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. I used this program (http://ilspy.net/) and able to find the source code from its binary file.

Answer (score 0):

If the project is corrupted it's likely gone and you'll need to look to your backups.

I've used a few different text editors. I find TextPad to be the best at opening files. I'm even able to open locked files with TextPad. I've been using it for years and I Love It.

Good Luck